# flash: Math.pow calculates wrong answers for larger numbers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

why is this so?

when i try out:

Math.pow(2,58)=288230376151711740
while in fact, it is 288230376151711744

or

Math.pow(2,57)=144115188075855870
while it really equals 144115188075855872

it just throws that number without any warning.
i would understand if it stopped going above some number in case of maximum value reached. however, this seems to calculate the first n digits correctly and then go wrong at the very end of the digits only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've ran out of Number type display precision. The trick is that with powers of 2 the actual value stored in the variable will be precise, while when you'll trace it the engine will truncate the displayed value by 16 digits, as it divides by 10 in process, and leftovers will eventually hit "machine zero" if compared to original value taken without exponential part. This is made to prevent white noise generated by imprecise floating-point division to be displayed. You can work around this issue if you'll advance to big integers/floating point numbers, that store more bits than a double precision number.

Comment: Well, I mean that a number that's a power of 2 has a mantissa of all zeroes (and an implicit leading one), and a proper exponential part, thus is precisely stored in a double precision number. BTW, is that true that there are 56 bits out of 64 for mantissa for double? Wikipedia says 52.

Comment: thank you for the answers. now i have to find a way how to represent a really large number in actionscript. do you have any recommendations?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=biginteger+actionscript for example, the problem is very old, and certain solutions exist for any of the programming languages. (BTW, these comments forbig LMGTFY... heh)